# Format a datetime without a varchar cast

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a `datetime` field. In this field current date is inserted manually in this format:

```
30/05/2013 0.00.00
```

I would automate this process. So i tried to retrieve current date from `GETDATE()` function and parse it with `CONVERT()` function, but this only works using `varchar` as target destination, but as I said: I still need `datetime`. What can I do?

Comment: Why are you converting? To insert? Or to display on the UI/Report

Comment: If you want to retrieve a DateTime, you'll retrieve a DateTime, not a format or wath so ever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Datetimes are all stored in the same, universal format. You would then pull that back out to your report or application and format according to the user's locale, or your own specified format accordingly.

A datetime field and/or object does not have a format.

If you want to insert the current date into a datetime field (excluding the time part), use the following:

```
insert into [MyTable] ([DateField])
values (cast(floor(cast(getdate() as float)) as datetime)
```

This will reset the hours, minutes and seconds to "0"

If you wanted to insert a date parameter, then you could use the following:

```
cast(floor(cast(@dateParam as float)) as datetime)
```

If you simply want to change how it is formatted within a result set, you could use:

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY
```

At the top of your statement, then, whenever you cast it as a varchar, you won't need to specify a format.

Remember, databases should not be formatting dates, your UI should handle this

Comment: So I could insert directly GETDATE()'s output and it will be displayed as DD/MM/YYYY h.m.s format?

Comment: It will be displayed however you pull the getdate from the database. If your language is set to "English (British)", it would show as dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm.ss, but if it was set to "English", it would show as MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm.ss

Answer (score 0):

To store current date without hour/minutes I usually use this:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 102), 102)
```

Comment: You should never rely on casting dates to strings and back again as formats can change, see my solution instead

Comment: Thanks! I took note of this alternative solution!